# A product to watch 3D on a non-3D TV

Tags: television

There are three main ways to deliver 3D:

- Anagylph, the type of 3D involving the old red-blue glasses
- Passive 3D, the type of 3D you see in movie theaters nowadays, involving circularly polarized light
- Active 3D, the type of 3D found in most 3D glasses, involving active-shutter glasses

Now you can view Anaglyph 3D on essentially any TV. And there are even products like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005SN3INA) which takes 3D content designed for Passive or Active 3D and converts them to Anaglyph so they can be viewed on non-3D TV's.

But my question is, are there any products that allow you to view either active or passive 3D on a non-3D TV? It seems there was such a product called [3DNOW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009E7WDLO) in 2012, but it appears to have been discontinued. Are there any similar products currently on the market?

I have a 4K TV, so resolution shouldn't be a problem.  And it has a high frame rate.